# Неправильно работает операция сравнения с числом 0.1

Tags: mysql, float

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT id, city, commision FROM sellers
WHERE commision > 0.1;
```

Вот вывод:

> id    city  commision
>   '1', 'London', '0.12'
>   '2', 'San Jose', '0.13'
>   '3', 'New York', '0.1'
>   '4', 'London', '0.11'
>   '7', 'Barcelona', '0.15'

В выводе присутствует строка, у которой значение столбца `commition` равно `0.1`, хотя в `WHERE` я пишу, что мне нужны только те строки, у которых `commition > 0.1`.
Тип `commition` - `FLOAT`. И, что интересно, для других чисел этого не наблюдается. Например, при запросе:

```
SELECT id, city, commision FROM sellers
WHERE commision > 0.12;
```

Получаем вывод:

> '7', 'Barcelona', '0.15'
>   '2', 'San Jose', '0.13'

То есть строка со значениями столбцов `'1', 'London', '0.12'`, как и дОлжно, пропускается.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос? Почему? Как исправить? Так устроено двоичное представление чисел,  в котором 0,1 невозможно записать вообще.

Comment: https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: *Тип commition - FLOAT.* Именно это и есть ошибка. Точные значения должны иметь тип DECIMAL.

Comment: так устроен float. ваше число 0.1 на самом деле может иметь значение под капотом мускуля равное 0.1000001 и это уже больше чем 0.1

Comment: @Эникейщик посмотрите ответ, я не могу быть уверен в его правильности(ответ мой).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути числа с плавающей запятой(в двоичном представлении, не `decimal`) вычисляются так:

```
(-1)^бит_знака_числа * мантисса * 1010^экспанента.
```

В нашем случае(0.1) получается так:

```
(-1)⁰ * 1.0 * 1010⁻¹ = 1.0 / 1010
```

Разумеется, результат получается неточным:

[image: https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/]

Так в чем же хранить такие числа? Ответ - `decimal`. Но в данном случае получится число с фиксированной точкой, что ограничит нас, но зато никаких проблем с числом быть не должно.
При создании столбца на месте типа нужно указать `DECIMAL(M, N)`, где `M` - кол-во чисел до точки, `N` - после. [Больше информации по теме можно получить здесь](http://tarlyun.com/blog/2011/03/22/xranenie-ne-celyx-chisel-v-mysql/).